# Is $|z\bar{z}^{-1}|=1,z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

$\bar{z}$ is the conjugation of $z$.

Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The result I got was if  $z = a+bi$ the Statement would be equivalent to $(a+bi)(a-bi)^{-1}$ which is equivalent to (according to my computation) $\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}+2\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}i$

Comment: You are almost there, compute the modulus of that number !

Comment: It's easier not to bother with real and imaginary parts, if you know that $|zw|=|z||w|$ and $|\overline{z}| = |z|$.  Of course you need $z \ne 0$ for your left side to be defined.

Comment: My next question Building upon this result is if $z\in S_1$ (Unit circle) is $z\bar{z}^{-1}=z^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Use that with $\bar z \ne 0$

$$|z\bar{z}^{-1}|=|z||\bar{z}^{-1}|=\frac{|z|}{|\bar{z}|}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|z|=|\bar{z}| \space \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\left| \frac{z_1}{z_2} \right| = \frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|} \space \forall z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}, z_2 \ne 0$